# Java Fermat Factorisation algorithm BigInteger not working

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger

I'm implementing Fermat Factorization algorithm using `BigInteger` so I can factor. But at the moment, the code is not working; it hangs for some reason. Could someone direct me to where the issue is, or let me know if my algorithm is incorrect? `BigInteger` makes life difficult, so I had to look for a square root method.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fermat
{
    /** Fermat factor **/
    public void FermatFactor(BigInteger N)
    {
        BigInteger a = sqrt(N);
        BigInteger b2 = a.multiply(a).subtract(N);

        while (!isSquare(b2)) {
            a = a.add(a);
            b2 = a.multiply(a).subtract(N);
        }

        BigInteger r1 = a.subtract(sqrt(b2));
        BigInteger r2 = N.divide(r1);
        display(r1, r2);
    }

    /** function to display roots **/
    public void display(BigInteger r1, BigInteger r2) {
        System.out.println("\nRoots = "+ r1 +" , "+ r2);    
    }

    /** function to check if N is a perfect square or not **/
    public boolean isSquare(BigInteger N) {
        BigInteger ONE = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger sqr = sqrt(N);

        if (sqr.multiply(sqr) == N  || (sqr.add(ONE)).multiply(sqr.add(ONE)) == N)
            return true;
        return false;
    }


    public static BigInteger sqrt(BigInteger x)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative argument.");
        }
        // square roots of 0 and 1 are trivial and
        // y == 0 will cause a divide-by-zero exception
        if (x == BigInteger.ZERO || x == BigInteger.ONE) {
            return x;
        } // end if
        BigInteger two = BigInteger.valueOf(2L);
        BigInteger y;
        // starting with y = x / 2 avoids magnitude issues with x squared
        for (y = x.divide(two);
                y.compareTo(x.divide(y)) > 0;
                y = ((x.divide(y)).add(y)).divide(two));
        if (x.compareTo(y.multiply(y)) == 0) {
            return y;
        } else {
            return y.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        }
    } // end bigIntSqRootCeil


    /** main method **/
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Fermat Factorization Test\n");
        System.out.println("Enter odd number");
        BigInteger N = scan.nextBigInteger();
        Fermat ff = new Fermat();
        ff.FermatFactor(N);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

I know I have a lot of mistakes, but any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `total == N` try `total.equals(N)`.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you for your reply. It did not work either. the value of total and N increases every time it gets executed.

Comment: You also have the same error in your `sqrt` method, where you use `==` instead of `equals` to compare with `BigInteger.ZERO` and `BigInteger.ONE` (by the way, you can use static imports to shorten that). Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with Fermat factorization.

Comment: @DavidConrad  The algorithms somehow is easy but BigInteger makes it hard to implement

Comment: As a strategy for getting a clearer view of what is going on in your code, write the algorithm out in pseudo-code, then interleave the pseudo-code as comments in your implementation.

Comment: Why do you return the ceiling of the sqrt (you add ONE if it is not a perfect square), instead of returning the floor? But I think the problem is in your `FermatFactor` method. By the way [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a nice [BigIntegerMath.sqrt()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v18.0/javadoc/com/google/common/math/BigIntegerMath.html) method.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan You are right but eventually got confused with BigInteger.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes that was my mistake and now i've fixed it and it works, i must've wrote it without noticing.  Thank you.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thank you for referring me to Guava but i'd rather prefer to use local methods than external ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "for" loop :

```
for (y = x.divide(two);
    y.compareTo(x.divide(y)) > 0;
    y = ((x.divide(y)).add(y)).divide(two));
```

does not terminate. Perhaps you could keep track of the values of the variable 'y', to guess when you have to stop.

Edit : that was wrong (see comments). The problem is in the line

```
a = a.add(a)
```

inside procedure FermatFactor. It should rather be

```
a = a.add(ONE)
```

In my machine I also had troubles with testing equalities using 'A == B'. The method 'A.equals(B)' fixed it.

Comment: You mean that i have to add a base case?

Comment: What do you mean by base case? You can show that during the execution of this loop, y assumes values greater than or equal to sqrt(x). However if sqrt(x) is not an integer... then y is always strictly greater than sqrt(x) and the loop doesn't terminate.

Comment: That isn't true in general, and indeed it gives good results for a number of cases I tried (such as 8675309). Can you give an example of a case for which it doesn't terminate? Still, I would suggest to the OP to use an existing BigInteger sqrt method such as a the one in Google's Guava library, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: @Sary Are you taking into account the fact that BigInteger divide is not real number divide?

Comment: Oops ! You are right. Sorry. The program looped on my machine with N=7. However there is another issue with the "while" loop in procedure FermatFactor. Are you sure that's the algorithm ?

Comment: @Sary your answer of changing a to ONE actually solved my issue. You are right about it, this is how it should be, i don't know how i missed this. Thank you.